# ASP.NET HttpHandler and WebResource.axd issues

Tags: asp.net, httphandler, sitefinity-4

I need a simple HttpHandler to handle specific non-existant paths in my ASP.NET project. I'm using sitefinity 4. I wrote the handler but whenever I try to run the site, I get a frustrating error

```
The WebResource.axd handler must be registered in the configuration to process this request.
```

I was putting the handler in the system.web part of the config but it looks liek VS2010 still uses IIS 6 for it's built in web server so I went ahead and switched it to use IIS 7 (local) and moved the registration of the handler to system.webServer and it works when I hit a non existant url but if I try to go to the site normally (valid url) I get that dang error again.

It worked once, giving me the correct site on a valid url but now it just continues to give me trouble.

How can I resolve this issue? I don't want to add that entry to the config as it wasn't there when I created the project and it only started when I added my handler.

EDIT: Only happens when I use Path="*" so how do I do a wildcard? I don't want to map a handler to catch a 404 page.

Comment: Have you tried to register WebResource.axd as the error "suggests"? If so, what was the result?

Comment: I didn't put it in the system.webServer yet but I did put it in the system.web and it's there right now...not working. But this is in IIS 7 (local) so thats probably why it's still complaining about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Froget it. No one seems to know even though I know i'm not the only one who has needed to do this. I got 404 to work but ONLY when I request a file, not a folder so thats a bust.

I found that Global.asax will hit under integrated mode so I just moved my code to the Application_BeginRequest() and it's working just fine. If anyone else has a better answer I will give them credit.

Answer (score -1):

for iis7 and iis7.5, handlers are registered in system.webserver. the httphandlers and httpmodules in system.web are ignored and are used for IIS 6 and classic mode.

i hope this was helpful!